# NSWindowController performClose: method not work

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow, keydown, nswindowcontroller

I' ve a subclass of `NSWindowController` where I need to put the code to close the associated `NSWindow` when I press the esc key on the keyboard.

I' ve found that in the `keyDown:` method the esc button is not handled so, after reading other question on this site and across the internet, i found that the best solution is to provide a `cancel:` method in the controller. In fact this work, I overrode the `cancel:` method and the `NSLog` that i put there works great when i press the esc key.

The problem is that if I replace the `NSLog` with a simple `[self.window performClose:self]` this not works and when i press the esc button nothing happen and the standard system beep for denied operation is played. What I miss to simply close my `NSWindow` in my code? thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/performClose:

The interesting bit is:

> ... If the window doesn’t have a close button or can’t be closed (for
>   example, if the delegate replies NO to a windowShouldClose: message),
>   the system emits the alert sound.

I think `[self.window close]` is what you want. If you only want to hide the window (and show it again later) you can use `[self.window orderOut:self]`

Comment: Thanks! As I aspect the solution was really simple but I could' t  figure it out without your help. Thanks again!